# How to combine columns in a dataframe based on strings contained in the column names?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe `all_data` with 14 columns that need to be combined into 4 columns.

So far, I have made objects for the raw columns name strings.

```
name_pattern <- c( "Geographic.area.name", "Geographic Area Name")
VoS_pattern <- c( "Total.value.of.shipment", "value of shipments")
NAICS_pattern <- c( "NAICS.code", "NAICS code")
industry_pattern <- c("Meaning.of.", "Meaning of NAICS code")
```

Here, for example, I have 5 columns that are contained by the strings in `VoS_pattern`, that I need to combine into one column.

I need to create objects containing all individual columns which will be united to one column. When there is only one string assigned the object, such as `NAICS_pattern <- "NAICS.code"` as opposed to `NAICS_pattern <- c( "NAICS.code", "NAICS code")`, the following works

`NAICS_col_names <- grep( NAICS_pattern, colnames( all_data ), value = TRUE )`

Unfortunately, it does not work when there are multiple strings assigned to the object, and the warning I receive is:

> In grep(NAICS_pattern, colnames(all_data), value = TRUE) :   argument
>   'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `paste` them together to a single one with `|`

```
grep(paste(NAICS_pattern, collapse="|"), colnames( all_data ), value = TRUE )
```